# Searching a substring in a string and its position

Tags: c, c-strings

I'm trying to write a code that checks if entered substring is in entered string. With some googling I was managed to do it. But I'm supposed to write a code that tells if the substring repeats several times.

For example, if string is `"ABBABBABAAABBBABABAA"` and substring is `"BABA"`, output should be between 5-8, 13-16, 15-18.

How can I improve my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  char sntnc[400], word[400], *ptr; 
  puts("Please enter a string: ");
  gets(sntnc);
  puts("\nEnter a substring to be searched: ");
  gets(word);
  ptr=strstr(sntnc,word);
  if (strstr(sntnc, word)==NULL)
    printf("\nThe string doesn't contains the substring.");
  else 
    printf("\nPositin of the substring in the string: %d.", ptr - sntnc + 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out the [KMP string matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you find an instance of the substring and print its location, increment `ptr` so it points to the next character, then call `strstr` again with `ptr` as the string to search.  Loop until it returns NULL:

```
ptr=strstr(sntnc,word);
if (strstr(sntnc, word)==NULL) {
   printf("\nThe string doesn't contains the substring.");
} else {
    do {
       printf("\nPositin of the substring in the string: %d.", ptr - sntnc + 1);
       ptr=strstr(ptr+1,word);
    while (ptr);
}
```

Also, the `gets` function is unsafe.  Since it performs no bounds checking on the input, it potentially allows writing past the end of the destination buffer which invokes undefined behavior.  Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but I need to look at it to understand how it does. Also, I've seen many people suggesting to use fgets instead of gets but for some reason it doesn't work on my code when I just replace them. Since I'm a newbie on coding, I didn't want to push my chance. Thank you once again.

Comment: So basically while works until ptr==NULL, right? I added a printf inside "do while" to see how it works and I think I get it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Emin Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.